# Assign dimensions from variables

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

I have netCDF dataset with `x`, `y` as spatial dimensions (in Lambert conic projection) which are just enumerated values [0:495], [0:309], and `lat`, `lon` variables as 2D meshes with shapes (309, 495).

I want to assign `lon`, `lat` variables to `x`, `y` dimensions to get projected data over longitudes and latitudes, but I couldn't find any reference how to do this.
Converting existing dataset would be great, but acceptable options are also recreating new netCDF dataset from existing, or generating hdf-5 instead.

---

Sorry to realize that my question is unintelligible. I'll try with another example which does not imply geographic spatial projection.

I have netCDF dataset with 3 dimensions. Vertical dimension `altitude` is expressed in units hPa, while dataset contains variable `height` which maps each `altitude` level to meters. I want to change netCDF dataset and assign `height` variable to `altitude` dimension. So that when I read netCDF dataset with a program of choice, it will read vertical dimension as `height` in meters, instead `altitude` in hPa.

Hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Do you have all the parameters needed for the Lambert projection?

Comment: If you mean the proj string, I have it, but that's not necessary as I have exact lat, lon coordinates for every x, y dimension point.

Comment: Reading your question and all the comments so far, it is still confusing (to me at least) what exactly you want.  Could you revise/elaborate?  What is the output if you do `ncdump -h` on your dataset?

Comment: @Spencer Hill, I edited my question and tried to explain with another example, hopefully easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the dimension altitude to height. This makes height (not altitude) the coordinate variable. The netCDF Operators (NCO) do this with:
ncrename -d altitude,height in.nc out.nc

Comment: Thanks Charlie for answering :) This is the kind of a solution I was hoping for.